# Split String in clo​j​ure and then print

Tags: arrays, string, printing, clojure

I'm new to clo​j​ure. I want to split a `String` and then print. If I do :

```
(.split "Dasher Dancer Prancer" " ")
```

It gives the `#<String[] [Ljava.lang.String;@64e0e8ca>` which is just the `toString()` of the array.

Then If I do :

```
(.length (.split "Dasher Dancer Prancer" " "))
```

it gives `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: length for class [Ljava.lang.String;`

Comment: If you got your answer, please pick one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`clojure.string/split`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.string/split) instead:

```
user=> (clojure.string/split "Dasher Dancer Prancer" #" ")
["Dasher" "Dancer" "Prancer"]
```

No need to use java interop for this.

If you need length, use [count](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/count):

```
user=> (count (clojure.string/split "Dasher Dancer Prancer" #" "))
3
```

The `.split` you're trying to call is a simple java method call on a `String`, which returns an array, which then is converted by repl to `String` by calling `toString` on it. As you noticed, it's not giving you the desired result.

`clojure.string/split` on the other hand, returns `clojure.lang.PersistentVector` which has `.toString` method that prints the contents as expected.

Comment: Good answer. What is the difference between ​`clojure.string/split` just `split`?

Comment: @javaguy what do you mean by `split`? `split` in what namespace? or did you mean `.split`?

Comment: @soulcheck Yeah I meant clojure.string/split just .split.

Answer (score 4):

You can use (alength) function:

```
(alength (.split "Dasher Dancer Prancer" " "))
```

> user=> (doc alength)
>       clojure.core/alength
>   ([array])
>     Returns the length of the Java array. Works on arrays of all
>     types.

(doc) and (find-doc) are really important for daily Clojure development.